# How do I make an autoencoder and make it work on extracting the feature of a stationary wave?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoders, homework

I have a project to complete in a day, and I know that doing it in a day is a bit far-fetched. The problem is this -

"Design an autoencoder with two neurons as the constriction, multiple hidden layers, and a vector from input neurons.

Make it work on extracting features of a stationary wave.

Then deconvolve what the constriction says.

Can you see wavevector(or frequency) and phase showing up in any way?

If you succeed in this past talk in getting somewhere meaningful, now make the input a wave (so you are now autoencoding a movie instead of stationary picture), and figure out what you should do with the autoencoder to derive some physical meaning."

Can anyone tell me what to do? What kind of things to learn and avoid? (I know basic Linear algebra, multivariable calculus and very basic probability theory of knowing what an expectation value is and one or two distributions, I know some C, not Python)

Comment: Hi Neeladri! If this is by any chance a homework question, make sure to use the homework tag :)

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn Did it!